# Add image URL to ACF Gallery images

Tags: wordpress, gallery, lightbox, advanced-custom-fields, imageurl

I have ACF set up in WP with a Gallery field. Currently I am displaying my images as follows:

```
             <p><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></p> 
                <?php $images = get_field('gallery_images');
                    if( $images ): ?>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                                    <li class="portrait float">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"  />
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>          
                    <?php endif; 
                ?>
```

I have also installed the Simple Lightbox Plugin but have been unsuccessful so far. How do I add the URL link of my ACF Gallery images. I have tried wrapping my image tag in a link tag with rel="lightbox" and several other variations including:

```
     <a href="<?php echo $image_large[0]; ?>"><img rel="lightbox[gallery_images] src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"  /></a>
```

Is there any way I can enable Attachment Display Settings for my ACF Gallery images in my WP post. I think this might be handy to have?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following which worked.

```
    <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"><img rel="lightbox[gallery_images]" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"  /></a>
```

All my images are full size so didn't need the following at all:

```
    echo $image_large[0];
```